# Reduce the height of the top panel on Elementary OS Freya

Tags: wingpanel

I want to know how i can reduce the height of the top panel, i've search on google but i cant`t find an answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the panel shorter by editing your system's stylesheet. If you haven't modified your system, the file you want to edit is `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`. You can adjust the height of the panel by reducing the padding in the selector `.composited-indicator`. The current version of the stylesheet doesn't style `.composited-indicator` directly, so you'll have to add a line for it.

`.composited-indicator` is a Gtk.MenuItem so it inherits all the style properties defined in `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` under the selector `.menu .menuitem`

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, can you give me an example of the line that i have to add? i`m not good with code :(

Comment: why do you tell all of that like we all know how to deal with this files... not anyone is experienced..

Comment: I'm not the person who answered, but: in my opinion, if you don't understand the answer you are better of leaving the system as it is to avoid problems. Read about gtk theming if you are interested and then begin to tweak it when you know how to.